# c# Noticing Table Changes

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I was wondering what's the easy way to notice if a change has occured to a `DataTable` .

Basically I have a timer that in its `TicK Event` Return a `DataTable` from `SQL Server`

My Methods :

```
    private void GetInfo(Timer T)
    {
        T.Interval = 2000;
        T.Start();
        T.Tick += T_Tick;
    } 


    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetInfo();
    }
```

My `Getinfo()` Display the datable returned in a `DataGridView`

What's the easiest or the cleanest way to Refresh the gridview only if a change has occured on a row or even on a single cell ?

**Because** it keeps refreshing the `DataGridview` even when no changes occured  I don't want to Refresh it if no changes has occured!

Change : means any new `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` Query Effected on the Table

EDIT : 
**like if  i m getting a new datatable from database (Modified than the actual one) how can i compare between them and if there are some changes or some differents display the new one in the datagridview**

Comment: DataTables have events you can subscribe to - not the same thing as changes to the database.

Comment: I know but it don't know how to combine it , like if a i m getting a new datatable from database (Modified than the actual one) how can i compare between them and if there are some changes or some differents display the new one in the datagridview

Comment: If you really want to be notified of changes to the underlying table, and it is SQL Server (not sure what 'SQL database' means) there is the SQL Dependency class

Comment: Yes sir but still don't know the cleanest way to compare between the two Datatables the Incoming one and the actual one

Comment: I dont understand the problem.  If you refresh the datatable (not the DataGridView, and not create a new DataTable) bound to a DGV, the changes show up automatically.  A DataAdapter does exactly this for you.  No timer required with SQLDependency

Comment: I know but i don't want to keep refreshing it cause when selecting a row in the DGV and the refresh Timer come up the Selected row back to it defaults row

Comment: take a look into SignalR, but other than that you either want to look at Tasks \ Multi Threading and connection factories

Comment: Again, you **dont** refresh the DataGridView, you **dont** build a new datatable.  If you refresh the current datatable/datasource only the changes will be picked up - it wont flicker, it wont loose the user's location, it wont throw away selected rows.  No need to compare and no need for a Timer with sql server

Comment: i tried what you said but refreshing the datatable don't change the DGV informations until you launch the Button where you give the source to the DGV

Comment: ...then your dataadapter is not set up properly (or you arent using a DA).  Its what they do.  Unforunately you have 3 or 4 issues and misconceptions bundled into one question which makes it hard to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** By comparing between tables if no differences noticed between the two `DataTables` , but if there is then the new `datatable` will be set as the source of the datatable